# Updating Component References to NuGet

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

With recent stable Visial Studio 2017 Enterprise Update v15.6.2 I get that nag message when the Xamarin.Forms solution is loaded.

[image]

I followed the [How to update](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/component-nuget/#Components_without_a_NuGet_migration_path) link but still get that message. The Components folder is in the solution directory and the dll is included as Reference.

[image]

[image]

That is my Visual Studio Version

[image]

Thanks for any help to get rid of the **Time to update** message dialog.

Comment: After removing any reference to  XamarinComponentReference in android .csproj the message dialog was gone.                                                            
<ItemGroup>
    <XamarinComponentReference Include="GCMClient">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <Version>1.0</Version>
    </XamarinComponentReference>
</ItemGroup>